# Node.js email-verification with mongoose

Tags: node.js, npm, mongoose, email-verification

I am working on Node.js and email-verification with passport and mongoose.
Now I am testing the code and got an error, but I can't fix it.
Here is my problem and code posted below:

My app.js i have

```
var nev = require('email-verification')(mongoose);
require('./routes/db/email-verification')(nev);
require('./routes/db/passport')(passport,nev);
```

my email-verificaiton.js

```
var User = require('./ModelUser');


module.exports = function(nev){
    nev.configure({
        ...
        ...
    },function(err,options){
            if(err)
                return err;
            console.log('test');
        });

    nev.generateTempUserModel(User,function(err,tempUserModel){
        if(err){
            return err;
        }

        console.log('checked');
});


};
```

my passport.js

```
module.exports = function (passport, nev) {

...
...

passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
        usernameField: 'email', //dummy string
        passwordField: 'password', //dummy string
        passReqToCallback: true
    }, function (req, email, password, done) {



        var newUser = new User();

        newUser.email = email;
        newUser.password = password;

        nev.createTempUser(newUser, function( err, existingPersistentUser, newTempUser){
            if(err) console.error(err);

            if(existingPersistentUser){
                console.log('E-mail already exists');
                return done(null, false, req.flash('signupMessage', 'E-mail already exists'));
            }
            if(newTempUser){
                var URL = newTempUser[nev.options.URLFieldName];

                nev.sendVerificationEmail(email, URL, function(err, info){

                if(err) console.error(err);
                    console.log('An email has been sent to you. Please check it to verify your account.');
                    return done(null);
                    })
                } else{
                    console.log('You have already signed up. Please check your email to verify your account.');
                    return done(null);
                }
            })
```

I got an error TypeError: Cannot read property 'createTempUser' of undefined
I dont know why my 'nev' variable is undefined in my passport.js.
pls anyone can help me>? this is very hard.

Comment: In you `app.js`, on the line directly after `var nev = require('email-verification')(mongoose);`, try adding `console.log(nev)` to see if it is undefined there, before passing it to the function being exported in `passport.js`

Comment: @PatNeedham Hello I add log right after var nev = require('email-verification')(mongoose); but it was not undefined there, so I put the same log right after module.exports = function (passport, nev) { it shows 4 logs one is same log as in app.js file, then it has 3 undefineds.

Comment: @PatNeedham Hi I fixed the problem thx!

Comment: What did you change inside the function?

Answer (score 0):

In `email-verificaiton.js`, change it to look something more like this:

```
function verification(nev) {
    nev.configure({
        ...
        ...
    },function(err,options){
            if(err)
                return err;
            console.log('test');
        });

    nev.generateTempUserModel(User,function(err,tempUserModel){
        if(err){
            return err;
        }

        console.log('checked');
});


};

module.exports = {verification}
```

And then inside `app.js` you can change

```
var nev = require('email-verification')(mongoose);
```

To become

```
var nev = require('email-verification').verification(mongoose);
```

Comment: I called passport.js multiple times in app.js so nev has the value at the first time , but others were undefined , so i fixed the problem by putting 3 lines in app.js to bottom of the code